# Gallery database design question regarding users in photos

Tags: database-design

I'm making a gallery, somewhat similar to Facebook's. I want users to be able to tag other users in photos, including non-registered users. Is it best to have a table `in_photo` with columns `(user_id, name, photo_id)` where `user_id` is null if the user is unregistered, and `name` is set, and vice-versa, or should I scrap the `name` column and create a temporary `user` or some other scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is any another metadata you'd store with the unregistered user - yes, create the temporary users or another table.

If all you store is name - I'd say the way you have it is fine.  Although 'name' isn't very descriptive.  Maybe 'unregistereduser_name' would be a better name for the column.